# Palindrome in java, asking the user for different inputs till they enter stop, the method should remove all spaces and make letters lower case

Tags: java, methods

public class Palindrome {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String string
    String reverse = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    string = scanner.nextLine();

    int length = string.length();

    for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + string.charAt(i);

    if (string.equals(reverse))
        System.out.println(string+" is a palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println(string+" is not a palindrome");

}
```

}

This is how far I came, not sure how to keep asking the user for input until they type stop in order to terminate the program. Moreover, I cant seem to get the program to change letters into lowercase before determining if it is a palindrome and to accept sentences.

Answer (score 1):

To keep asking user for new input just wrap your computation into infinite loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) { // keep asking forever
            System.out.println("Enter a string:");
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            if (string.equals("stop")) break; // if stop entered - leave the loop
            string = string.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", ""); // convert string to LC and remove spaces

            if (string.equals(new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString()))
                System.out.println(string + " is a palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println(string + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That somehow works, however, it takes two times of typing stop in order for the program to terminate....

Answer (score 0):

Try this changed version of your code. Just added a `while` block with `break` statement.

```
    public class Palindrome{

    public static void main( String args[] ){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        while (true) {
            String string = "";
            String reverse = "";

            System.out.println( "Enter a string:" );
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            if( string == null || string.trim().equals( "" ) ) break;

            int length = string.length();

            for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                reverse = reverse + string.charAt( i );

            if (string.equals( reverse ))
                System.out.println( string + " is a palindrome" );
            else
                System.out.println( string + " is not a palindrome" );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The user has to specifically enter stop in order for the program to terminate.